# question mark (?) in shell variable

Tags: string, shell, variables

I want to use a variable with this name: topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?

how can I do it in a shell script (i.e., using the question mark)? I tried:

```
{topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?}="something"
```

but it's not understood in my shell script (myfile.sh using in the first row #!/bin/sh).

Any hint will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't. That's not a valid identifier in bash. See the definition of `name` at http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Definitions

> name
>
> > A word consisting solely of **letters, numbers, and underscores**, and beginning with a letter or underscore. Names are used as shell variable and function names. Also referred to as an identifier.

Comment: I see the `dash` man page says "Variables set by the user must have a name consisting solely of alphabetics, numerics, and underscores - the first of which must not be numeric."

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot use `?` in unix shell variable names. In fact many other special characters such as period, comma, `?` aren't allowed.

This is the regex for shell variable names:

```
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Comment: Yes shell is pretty rigid about naming the variable (probably because it was written in C therefore followed all C conventions)

Comment: The correct regex is: `[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*` (no plus sign needed). Check general.h in bash source (search for `legal shell identifier`).

Comment: Thanks. Yes indeed @BinaryZebra, `+` was a typo (fixed now).

Answer (score 0):

? cannot be part of a variable name like : % = and lot more special meaning for shell. In this case it will try to find a file starting with your variable name and 1 character (any character). Unless you have one that can be executed by hte environment, it will return an error.

```
ksh:
{topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?}="something"
sh: {topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?}=something:  not found.

bash
{topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?}="something"
bash: {topMiddleOligocenetoUpperEocene?}=something: command not found
```